# Embedding htmlwidgets in RHTML

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, r-highcharter

I am transitioning an internal dashboard from rmarkdown to rhtml. All of my htmlwidgets graphics are rendering as static images when I knit to html. This doesn't happen in the rmarkdown version of this document.

Here's a minimum reproducible example.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Highcharter in R HTML</title>
</head>
<body>

<!--begin.rcode setup, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE
library(tidyverse)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(highcharter)
library(dygraphs)
library(leaflet)
end.rcode-->

<p>This base plot works:</p>
<!--begin.rcode fig.width=7, fig.height=6
plot(cars)
end.rcode-->

<p>Unfortunately, this Highcharter chart renders as a static image and cuts off most of the data:
<!--begin.rcode
highchart() %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = citytemp$month) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "Tokyo", data = citytemp$tokyo) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "New York", data = citytemp$new_york) 
end.rcode-->

<p>Here's an example chart using dygraphs instead of highcharter:</p>
<!--begin.rcode
dygraph(nhtemp, main = "New Haven Temperatures") %>% 
  dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c("1920-01-01", "1960-01-01"))
end.rcode-->

<p>And here's leaflet:</p>
<!--begin.rcode dev = 'svg'
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(0,0,1)
end.rcode-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HTML widgets are currently only supported in R Markdown documents and Shiny apps. It is not impossible to support Rhtml, but someone has to volunteer to work on it (it requires reading the source code of the rmarkdown package).

Comment: Thank you for explaining, @YihuiXie! If you submit that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather wait for someone to actually implement it :)

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? I am having the same issue: using highcharter with Rhtml with no success. Thanks!

Comment: @BrunoGuarita unfortunately not, I went back to using rmarkdown.

Comment: thanks @AndrewBrēza! I did the same.